# How to Create a Flag Based on Date Values in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a sample table as follows:

```
|  name | startdate | enddate    | flg |
|-------|-----------|------------|-----|
| John  | 6/1/2018  | 7/1/2018   |     |
| John  | 10/1/2018 | 11/1/2018  |     |
| John  | 12/1/2018 | 12/20/2018 |     |
| Ron   | 3/1/2017  | 9/1/2017   |     |
| Ron   | 5/1/2018  | 10/1/2018  |     |
| Jacob | 6/10/2018 | 6/12/2018  |     |
```

What I want in the output: If a person has a 'startdate' within 60 days (or 2 months) of an 'enddate' values; then set the flg as 1 for that person. else have the flg as 0. 
For example: John has a record of startdate on December 1st; which is within 60 days of one of the enddate for this person (November 1st 2018). So, the flg for this person is set to 1.

So, the output should look like as:

```
| Name  | startdate | enddate    | flg |
|-------|-----------|------------|-----|
| John  | 6/1/2018  | 7/1/2018   | 1   |
| John  | 10/1/2018 | 11/1/2018  | 1   |
| John  | 12/1/2018 | 12/20/2018 | 1   |
| Ron   | 3/1/2017  | 9/1/2017   | 0   |
| Ron   | 5/1/2018  | 10/1/2018  | 0   |
| Jacob | 6/10/2018 | 6/12/2018  | 0   |
```

Any idea please?

Comment: can you post your attempts at solving this?

Comment: Why is Jacob's flag 0?

Comment: @VK_217 Jacob's flag is 0; because, there is no other records for Jacob where the startdate starts within 60 days of the enddate (which is 6/12/2018).

Comment: @Tanvir 6/10/2018 is not within 60 days of 6/12/2018?

Comment: Are you comparing the startdate and endate from previous row? In that case, you will need to use lag

Comment: @VK_217 yes; I am comparing dates from previous rows (for a specific person)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Date Functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions): Use `datediff` and `case`

```
select Name,startdate,enddate,
       case when datediff(enddate,startdate) < 60 then 1 else 0 end flag
from table
```

If you are comparing the previous row's enddate, use `lag()`

```
select Name,startdate,enddate,
    case when datediff(startdate,prev_enddate) < 60 then 1 else 0 end flag
from 
(
    select Name,startdate,enddate,
       lag(endate) over(partition by Name order by startdate,enddate) as prev_enddate
    from table
) t
```

Comment: This CASE statement logic will work for each of the individual rows; right? But I need to cross-check between the records for each of the specific persons. 
So, all the startdate of John will have a cross check with the enddates. 

John's flag set to 1 because John has a record of startdate on December 1st; which is within 60 days of one of the enddate value which is November 1st 2018.

Answer (score 0):

Use `lag` to get the enddate of the previous row (per name). After this the `flag` can be set per name using `max` window function with a `case` expression that checks to see if the 60 day diff is satisfied at least once per name.

```
select name
      ,startdate
      ,enddate
      ,max(case when datediff(startdate,prev_end_dt) < 60 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by name) as flag
from (select t.*
            ,lag(enddate) over(partition by name order by startdate) as prev_end_dt
      from table t
     ) t
```